# Django restframework getting WSGIRequest instead of rest_framework.request.Request

Tags: python, django

i'm creating a rest api with django 1.8 and djangorestframework and also creating the client side using extjs 6.2, i'm getting this error when i send an ajax request to the server
**'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'query_params'** my view is recieving a WSGIRequest object instead of the Request
 object, what bothers me is that i'm getting this error now when creating any view, all other(previously created) work fine, here are my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',)
```

and here are both the django view and extjs ajax request

**django view**

```
api_view(["GET"])
def testView(request):
    print(request.__class__)
    req = json.loads(request.query_params['array'])# here it gives the error 
    lolo = {"response":"data"}
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

**extjs Ajax request**

```
    var data = 'insert':{idlineapresupuesto_id:1, idusuario_id:1, nombre:"aaaaaa"}
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url :"http://127.0.0.1:8000/editarConcGastosView/?format=json",
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    params: {array: Ext.JSON.encode(data)},
    success : function(response){
    var jsonResp = Ext.util.JSON.decode(response.responseText);//Guarda en jsonResp la respuesta de la peticion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't used the decorator properly: you need an `@`.

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def testView(request):
```

Comment: AssertionError: The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not <classname>